# crontab every minute in a hour range and dow range?

Tags: linux, cron

I was trying to execute a script every minute from 8:00 to 17:00, only from Mondays to Thursdays but it is not working for me. Instead, launching the script manually works fine.

The script counts with exec permissions.

What am I missing?

I tried the following:

```
* 8-17 * * 1-4 [ -f /mnt/flash/scripts/cw.sh ] && /mnt/flash/scripts/cw.sh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks Like there are no such issues in the cron syntax. Please run `date` and Match local time and server time, because it may be possible that it differs most of the time.

For More Reliability add Logging for this cron like this:

```
* 8-17 * * 1-4 [ -f /mnt/flash/scripts/cw.sh ] && /mnt/flash/scripts/cw.sh >> /mnt/flash/scripts/cron.log 2>&1
```

You will get logs at `/mnt/flash/scripts/cron.log` SO that you can check and validate if there are any issues.

Comment: Date is well adjusted. I also tried to print logs as you said, and it did not worked, so the problem may be in crontab. Please notice this is an embedded Linux, with a simplified BusyBox version of crontab, it may not cointain the whole functionality. Knowing the syntax is OK is enough for me. Thank you for your response!